# How to define typedef for a range of float numbers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want a property that will only accept float values between 0 and 1. I could do that in a standard way by defining float_t or double_t type for the property, but doubting, are there more elegant ways for that?

Comment: This question is hard to understand...you want a property that will only accept values between 0 and 1?

Comment: Yes. Did correction to the sentence style.

Comment: What should happen if it receives a value above 1 or below 0?

Comment: Then on-screen objects will be shown incorrectly.

Comment: I mean, what should your program do?  Truncate?  Error?  You can just clamp the value in your property setter if you want.

Comment: Such errors should be caught during development, so rising exception with NSAssert is pretty acceptable for me. From user experience point of view, it's better to handle such error in a more friendly manner by truncating it (because the values are just used for viewing on-screen objects) and sending some error log report or etc., but currently we do not use any solid error handling mechanisms :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it the standard way - define a `double`/`float` property and check for validity in the setter - example:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) float property;

@synthesize property = _property;

- (void)setProperty:(float)property {
   NSAssert(property >= 0.0f && property <= 1.0f, @"Invalid value passed to property setter.").   

   _property = property;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(Objective-)C doesn't support subrange types. For that you need Ada (or a few others). The best you can do is implement checks in your setters.